# What is the impact of ReSharper's "Run tests even if Code Coverage is enabled" for MSTest?

Tags: resharper, mstest, code-coverage

In the options menu of ReSharper, under Tools > Unit Testing > MSTest, you can enable MSTest, and then there is a checkbox "Run tests even if Code Coverage is enabled".

Wat is the impact of enabling this option?

It was initally off, but as Code Coverage is enabled on our project, I had to check this option for ReSharper to run the unit tests. But why would ReSharper, by default, not want to run MSTest unit tests when Code Coverage is enabled?

Comment: This option is not longer there in the latest ReSharper 6.1.1
However, I have [asked](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-276666) the responsible developer to comment on reasons behind its introduction in earlier versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, ReSharper test runner must have had problems with MSTest when Code Coverage is enabled. I haven't explored this in full detail, because, as gorhoroh mentioned in the comment on my question, the option is no longer there.

If anyone cares to elaborate on this further, I'll be happy to mark that as an answer, provided it really explains what the implications were of course.